# Unable to understand F-omega term

Tags: lambda-calculus, system-f

I am reading a paper on F<sub>ω</sub>, and cannot understand the reasoning behind this statement:

> The type term of type (∀γ:*. F γ → β) shows that F is a constant function that always returns β.

I guess 'F γ → β' is the type term, i.e., an arrow type. This arrow type is the type of a function that takes an argument of type computed by the type application 'F γ' and returns a value of type β.

If this is the case, why should F be a constant (type) function that always returns β? Can't it be any arbitrary type function, one that returns, say, α, and still satisfy the typechecker?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I think the reason is [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity).

If 'F γ' could return any type, for example α, the function (whose type is conveyed by the ∀ type) would have a type of α → β.

Parametricity dictates that all instances of this polymorphic function should have the same behaviour, which is only possible if it is the identity function, i.e., of type β → β, therefore implying that 'F γ' always returns β.